# python how to replace or split on \r for lines from string list

Tags: python, paramiko

I have several lines of output similar to the following below from a `paramiko` ssh session. I am splitting first based on `\n`  and storing in a list each line. So the entire ssh session comes in as a complete string, therefore I split based on `\n`. however there are `\r` in here, see below.  if I try to split again on `\r` it fails because I already have a list.

```
|\r/\r-\r\\r\\\r|\r/\r[2K\r00:31:43 - Executing system_health v107
```

if I paste the text into notepad++ the `\r` look like returns or new lines.

```
'|

/

-

\\

|

/

[2K

00:31:43 - Executing system_health v107'
```

How can I take each line that is read in Python similar to this line

```
|\r/\r-\r\\r\\\r|\r/\r[2K\r00:31:43 - Executing system_health v107
```

and have it further split/slice into lines in another list? or some other method. the ultimate goal would be to remove the `\n` and `\r` and have each line as a line in a list. I could then remove ones i don't need.

Comment: You can just use `[line.strip() for line in lines]` or just split on `\r\n` to begin with.

Comment: Can you give the actual starting string , where you have `\n` as well? I think if you want to just split based on all whitespaces, you can use `.split()` , without any parameters. Or you can try `.split('\r\n')` .

Comment: @AnandSKumar Will your suggestion split on *all* whitespace? This might not be the desired behavior.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yea, it would. we can try spliting on `\r\n` as well as COLDSPEED suggested.

Comment: @AnandSKumar That seems more appropriate, but we cannot know for sure until the OP shows an example "original string" before any splitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of strings, all you have to do is iterate over the list, working on each string. In this case you appear to want another list of the results. Given the minimal data you have supplied.

```
>>> a=["|\r/\r-\r\\r\\\r|\r/\r[2K\r00:31:43 - Executing system_health v107","|\r/\r-\r\\r\\\r|\r/\r[2K\r00:31:44 - Executing system_health v108"]
>>> b=[]
>>> for i in a:
...     x = i.split('[2K\r')
...     b.append(x[-1])
... 
>>> b
['00:31:43 - Executing system_health v107', '00:31:44 - Executing system_health v108']
```

Within the `for i in a:` loop you can take as many steps as required to manipulate the data, before appending it to the new list (b)
Note: I am assuming each string as `[2K\r` before the time-stamp, that may not necessarily be the case but the principal remains the same.

Comment: thanks, i think i was just tired and over thought the whole thing. thanks for you words of wisdom, yeah just split on \n, split on \r, then the list from the splits on \r for each line i was able to exclude certain lines i didn't need.